# object property not being deserialized

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, xml-serialization

using svcutil i generated code from schema files. So far, all objects serialize and deserialize ok except this "Item" property:

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Order=2)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("AbstractQuery", typeof(AbstractQueryType), Order=2)]
    public object Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
```

When i try to cast the Item object to type QueryType which implements AbstractQuery i get an error saying:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' to type
>   'OGC.CSW.ebRIMProfile.QueryType'

I'm trying to do this:

```
(QueryType) test = (QueryType)Request.GetRecords.Item;
```

**I don't want XML i want my objects, Any ideas?**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it by adding this extra line:

Before:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Order=2)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("AbstractQuery", typeof(AbstractQueryType), Order=2)]
```

After:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Order=2)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("AbstractQuery", typeof(AbstractQueryType), Order=2)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Query", typeof(QueryType), Order = 2)]
```

Comment: What does "Order" do? Can you elaborate on it, and why it is 2?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen it `sets the explicit order in which the elements are serialized or deserialized` [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)